# fixed fill for different sections of a density plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given draws from a `rnorm`, and cutoff `c` I want my plot to use the following colors:

1. Red for the section that is to the left of `-c`
2. Blue for the section in between `-c` and `c`
3. and Green for the section that is to the right of `c`

For example, if my data is:

```
set.seed(9782)
mydata <- rnorm(1000, 0, 2)
c <- 1
```

I want to plot something like this:

[image]

But if my data is all to the right of `c` the whole plot should be green. Similarly, if all is between `-c` and `c` or to the left of `-c` the plot should be all red or blue.

This is the code I wrote:

```
MinD <- min(mydata)
MaxD <- max(mydata)

df.plot <- data.frame(density = mydata)

if(c==0){
  case <- dplyr::case_when((MinD < 0 & MaxD >0) ~ "L_and_R",
                           (MinD > 0) ~ "R",
                           (MaxD < 0) ~ "L")
}else{
  case <- dplyr::case_when((MinD < -c & MaxD >c) ~ "ALL",
                           (MinD > -c & MaxD > c) ~ "Center_and_R",
                           (MinD > -c & MaxD <c) ~ "Center",
                           (MinD < -c & MaxD < c) ~ "Center_and_L",
                           MaxD < -c ~ "L",
                           MaxD > c ~ "R")
}

# Draw the Center

if(case %in% c("ALL", "Center_and_R", "Center", "Center_and_L")){
  ds <- density(df.plot$density, from = -c, to = c)
  ds_data_Center <- data.frame(x = ds$x, y = ds$y, section="Center")
} else{
  ds_data_Center <- data.frame(x = NA, y = NA, section="Center")
}

# Draw L

if(case %in% c("ALL", "Center_and_L", "L", "L_and_R")){
  ds <- density(df.plot$density, from = MinD, to = -c)
  ds_data_L <- data.frame(x = ds$x, y = ds$y, section="L")
} else{
  ds_data_L <- data.frame(x = NA, y = NA, section="L")
}

# Draw R

if(case %in% c("ALL", "Center_and_R", "R", "L_and_R")){
  ds <- density(df.plot$density, from = c, to = MaxD)
  ds_data_R <- data.frame(x = ds$x, y = ds$y, section="R")
} else{
  ds_data_R <- data.frame(x = NA, y = NA, section="R")
}

L_Pr <- round(mean(mydata < -c),2)
Center_Pr <- round(mean((mydata>-c & mydata<c)),2)
R_Pr <- round(mean(mydata > c),2)

filldf <- data.frame(section = c("L", "Center", "R"), 
                     Pr = c(L_Pr, Center_Pr, R_Pr), 
                     fill = c("red", "blue", "green")) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(section = as.character(section))


if(c==0){
  ds_data <- suppressWarnings(dplyr::bind_rows(ds_data_L, ds_data_R)) %>% 
    dplyr::full_join(filldf, by = "section") %>% filter(Pr!=0) %>% 
    dplyr::full_join(filldf, by = "section") %>% mutate(section = ordered(section, levels=c("L","R"))) 
  ds_data <- ds_data[order(ds_data$section), ] %>%  
    filter(Pr!=0) %>% 
    mutate(Pr=scales::percent(Pr))
}else{
  ds_data <- suppressWarnings(dplyr::bind_rows(ds_data_Center, ds_data_L, ds_data_R)) %>% 
    dplyr::full_join(filldf, by = "section") %>% mutate(section = ordered(section, levels=c("L","Center","R"))) 
  ds_data <- ds_data[order(ds_data$section), ] %>%  
    filter(Pr!=0) %>% 
    mutate(Pr=scales::percent(Pr))
}

fillScale <- scale_fill_manual(name = paste0("c = ", c, ":"),
                               values = as.character(unique(ds_data$fill)))

p <- ggplot(data = ds_data, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=Pr)) + 
  geom_area() + fillScale
```

Alas, I cannot figure out how to assign the colors to the different sections while keeping the percentages as labels for the colors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the `density` function to create the data frame we'll actually plot. Then, We use the `cut` function to create groups using ranges of the data values.  Finally, we calculate the probability mass for each group and use those as the actual legend labels.

We also create a labeled vector of colors to ensure that the same color always goes with a given range of x-values, regardless of whether the data contains any values within a given range of x-values.

The code below packages all this into a function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

fill_density = function(x, cc=1, adj=1, drop_levs=FALSE) {

  # Calculate density values for input data
  dens = data.frame(density(x, n=2^10, adjust=adj)[c("x","y")]) %>% 
    mutate(section = cut(x, breaks=c(-Inf, -1, cc, Inf))) %>% 
    group_by(section) %>% 
    mutate(prob = paste0(round(sum(y)*mean(diff(x))*100),"%"))

  # Get probability mass for each level of section
  # We'll use these as the label values in scale_fill_manual
  sp = dens %>% 
    group_by(section, prob) %>% 
    summarise %>% 
    ungroup

  if(!drop_levs) {
   sp = sp %>% complete(section, fill=list(prob="0%"))
  }

  # Assign colors to each level of section
  col = setNames(c("red","blue","green"), levels(dens$section))

  ggplot(dens, aes(x, y, fill=section)) +
    geom_area() +
    scale_fill_manual(labels=sp$prob, values=col, drop=drop_levs) +
    labs(fill="")
}
```

Now let's run the function on several different data distributions:

```
set.seed(3)
dat2 = rnorm(1000)
grid.arrange(fill_density(mydata), fill_density(mydata[mydata>0]),
             fill_density(mydata[mydata>2], drop_levs=TRUE), 
              fill_density(mydata[mydata>2], drop_levs=FALSE),
             fill_density(mydata[mydata < -5 | mydata > 5], adj=0.3), fill_density(dat2),
             ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: close, but not exactly. I want to show the legend and have it be equal to the probability corresponding to each section.

Comment: almost but not exactly right. The second plot should be green because everything is to the right of `c`. Similarly, if I set c to 100 everything should be blue because everything will be between -100 and 100

Comment: The second plot, mydata[mydata>2], should be green because all the data is to the right of c==1.

Comment: I didn't consider the case where two sections had the same probability mass (both zero in the case you flagged). This results in duplicate factor labels and only the first level of section with the given factor label get's used. I've fixed that in the updated code.

Comment: I just simplified the code. I forgot that I could just use the `labels` argument in `scale_fill_manual` to set the labels to be the probability mass values. I've also added an argument that allows you to keep or drop missing `section` levels.